# Power analysis for orthogonal polynomials

Tags: polynomial, gpower

Use GPower for power analysis for cubic estimator in orthogonal polynomial regression?

I would like to determine the sample size I need in order to find a significant cubic estimator in an orthogonal polynomial regression (which I computed with R). I was wondering whether I could do this with Gpower? - I can compute the Effect size f2 manually (utilizing the R2 for the cubic and the linear regression in the f2-formula), and maybe then I could compute a power analysis with Gpower, using an F-Test (Statistical test: Linear multiple regression: Fixed model,R-squared increase)?
Thanks for your help in advance! :)